# Java Application with Asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk

I am working on a project. I just want to get the status of sip account of an Asterisk server from my Java application? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What happens when you google "java asterisk"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the configuration of your asterisk service? Is it running on a database? Are you using any 3rd party billing software along with asterisk? What OS are you running on? What version of asterisk is it?

There are definitely ways to do what you are wanting to accomplish. Have you looked at the 'asterisk-java' library? http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html

Comment: Iam using TrixBOx with the basic functionality of sip calls on one server. There is java application on other server from which i want to get access of trixbox database and status of sip client.

Answer (score 0):

May you access the database of asterisk directly from Java (JDBC driver) and read from sip.flags ?